# Get all public folders / shared contacts from EWS office365 with PHP

Tags: php, exchangewebservices, microsoft-graph-api, php-ews

I'm building a simple contact book from office 365, that lists all the shared contacts of my company.
I was trying with Graph and EWS too, but i can't figure out what is wrong.

Searching in the [Microsoft Graph explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) seems to be no chance to see my "Other Contacts" -> "All Contacts" folder.
I've been trying with "/me/contactFolders" endpoint and with "/people" endpoint. Non of them gave me results.

I also used a [php-ews](https://github.com/Garethp/php-ews/) library (the project is build on Laravel) to access to the folders via Exchange, with no luck.
using [this example](https://github.com/Garethp/php-ews/blob/master/examples/contacts/listContacts.php), i'm able to list just my contact, without any chance to see other folders or other kind of contacts.

Does anybody have any tip for a newbbie?!

thanks in advance.
**EDIT**
this is the Controller that works with PHP-EWS library

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use garethp\ews\ContactsAPI as ContactsAPI;

use garethp\ews\API;
use garethp\ews\API\Enumeration;
use garethp\ews\API\Type;
use garethp\ews\API\ExchangeWebServices;
//use garethp\ews\API\ExchangeAutodiscover;
//use garethp\ews\API\Exception\AutodiscoverFailed;
class SharedContatctsController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function index()
    {
      # code...

      $mail='developeremail@example.com';
      $pwd='password';
      $version='Exchange2016';
      //$apiS = ExchangeAutodiscover::getAPI($mail, $pwd);
      //$server=$apiS->getClient()->getServer();
      $server='mail.example.com;
      $api = ContactsAPI::withUsernameAndPassword($server, $mail, $pwd);
      $contacts = $api->getContacts();
      //return print($api->getFolderId());
      //If you want to get contacts within a folder
      //$folder = $api->getFolderByDisplayName('Altri Contatti', 'contacts');
      //$contacts = $api->getContacts($folder->getFolderId());
      return view('shared',array('contacts'=>$contacts,'displayName'=>$contacts['displayName']));
    }

}
```

This is the Controller that (quite works) displays the "BackupContacts" folder that is in the same directory as "Contact"

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Microsoft\Graph\Graph;
use Microsoft\Graph\Model;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class OutlookController extends Controller
{
public function contacts()
{
  if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
  }

  $tokenCache = new \App\TokenStore\TokenCache;

  $graph = new Graph();
  $graph->setAccessToken($tokenCache->getAccessToken());

  $user = $graph->createRequest('GET', '/me')
                ->setReturnType(Model\User::class)
                ->execute();

  $contactsQueryParams = array (
    // // Only return givenName, surname, and emailAddresses fields
    //"\$select" => "displayName,scoredEmailAddresses",
    // Sort by given name
    //"\$orderby" => "givenName ASC",
    // Return at most 10 results
    "\$orderby"=>"displayName",
    "\$top" => "1000"
  );

  $getContactsUrl = '/me/contactFolders/{BackuPlderId-retrieved-with-Graph}/contacts/?'.http_build_query($contactsQueryParams);
  $contacts = $graph->createRequest('GET', $getContactsUrl)
                    ->addHeaders(array ('X-AnchorMailbox' => $user->getMail()))
                    ->setReturnType(Model\Contact::class)
                    ->execute();

  return view('contacts', array(
    'username' => $user->getdisplayName(),
    'usermail' => $user->getMail(),
    'contacts' => $contacts
  ));
}
}
```

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but ***you need to help yourself first. :-)*** After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: Sorry @JayBlanchard. Just Edited to make it Clearer.

Answer (score 2):

The `/me/contacts` will return only the contacts in the *current user's* default contact folder. Similarly, the `/me/contactFolders` will only return the contact folders for the *current user's* mailbox (and an empty result if there isn't anything beyond their default folder.

The key here is the `/me` element. This is synonymous with `currently authenticated user`. So if the user who authenticated was `person@company.com` both `/me/contacts` and `/users/person@company.com/contacts` would return the exact same results.

The currently isn't a method for retrieving Organization Contacts (i.e. contacts stored in your GAL) from the `/v1.0` API set. There is however an [orgContact](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/orgcontact) object in the `/beta` API so support is forthcoming.